# datetime.strptime devuelve objetos 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

estoy intentando escribir un módulo sencillo para almacenar datos de fecha a partir de la información introducida por el usuario:

```
import datetime

formato_dia = ("%Y%m%d","%Y/%m/%d", "%Y-%m-%d")

def dia_manual():
    while True:
        entrada_dia = input("""Escriba la fecha para la que desea pedir cita previa
(AAAAMMDD, AAAA/MM/DD ó AAAA-MM-DD):
""")
        try:
            for i in formato_dia:
                try:
                    return(datetime.datetime.strptime(entrada_dia, i))
                    break
                except:
                    continue
            break
        except:
            print("No se ha introducido una fecha con un formato válido. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo.")
            continue

print("Ha solicitado una cita previa para el día: "+str(dia_manual()))
```

Necesitaría saber:

1. Si introduzco una fecha correctamente el resultado de
   `dia_manual()` también es correcto, es decir, se genera un objeto
   `datetime.date` que contiene la información introducida. Pero: Al
   introducir cualquier otro valor o una fecha incorrecta, no se genera
   una excepción, que debería ir seguida de una nueva solicitud de la
   información al usuario. En lugar de esa excepción,
   `datetime.strptime` devuelve un objeto `NoneType`. ¿Por qué?.
2. En la última línea necesitaría utilizar `strftime`. ¿Cómo puedo saber
   qué formato utilizó `strptime` para pasárselo como argumento?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se esta lanzando el error, eso es verificable si añadimos un print en except:

```
try:
    return(datetime.datetime.strptime(entrada_dia, i))
    break
except:
    print("error")
    continue
```

Si colocamos un valor errorneo usando lo anterior obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
error
error
error
Ha solicitado una cita previa para el día: None
```

Por lo que vemos que si el string no concuerda con algunos de los formatos se recorrera el loop y se lanzaran las excepciones pero al no haber retorno explicito se retornara nada, es decir None.

Si deseas obtener el formato python permite retornar múltiples valores:

```
import datetime

formato_dia = ("%Y%m%d","%Y/%m/%d", "%Y-%m-%d")

def dia_manual():
    while True:
        entrada_dia = input("""Escriba la fecha para la que desea pedir cita previa (AAAAMMDD, AAAA/MM/DD ó AAAA-MM-DD): """)
        for formato in formato_dia:
            try:
                return datetime.datetime.strptime(entrada_dia, formato) , formato
            except ValueError:
                pass
        print("No se ha introducido una fecha con un formato válido. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo.")

resultado = dia_manual()
if resultado is not None:
    dtime, formato = resultado
    print("Ha solicitado una cita previa para el día: {}".format(dtime))
    print("El formato elegido es {}".format(formato))
```

Nota: si te das cuenta el try-except externo no tiene sentido, que no haya coincidencia en el for-loop no va a lanzar ningun error.

---

Actualización:

Si quieres imprimer el string con el formato original solo retornalo:

```
import datetime

formato_dia = ("%Y%m%d","%Y/%m/%d", "%Y-%m-%d")

def dia_manual():
    while True:
        entrada_dia = input("""Escriba la fecha para la que desea pedir cita previa (AAAAMMDD, AAAA/MM/DD ó AAAA-MM-DD): """)
        for formato in formato_dia:
            try:
                datetime.datetime.strptime(entrada_dia, formato)
                return entrada_dia
            except ValueError:
                pass
        print("No se ha introducido una fecha con un formato válido. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo.")

print("Ha solicitado una cita previa para el día: {}".format(dia_manual()))
```

Comment: La idea de plantear un bloque try-except por fuera del for era recoger la excepción "No hay siguiente elemento iterable" (una vez que ha probado los 3 formatos) y al saltar esa excepción pedir otra vez que se introduzcan los datos de fecha.

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor ¿quien va a lanzar esa excepcion?, el for-loop no emite ninguna excepcion

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor Una excepcion se lanza cuando el valor que se maneja no es el esperado, pero un for-loop no espera que se termine de iterar, puede pararse en el medio, o hasta no ingresar al for-loop.

Comment: Tenemos 4 bloques: 
While(Try/Ex(For(Try/Ex)))
Cuando se genera la última excepción en el Try/Ex de dentro, se lanza "continue" pero ese continue no puede ejecutarse porque ya has iterado sobre todos los elementos, entonces for devuelve una excepción que tiene que ser recogida por el Try/Ex que está por fuera de él e inmediatamente dentro del While

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor los try-except externos no tiene sentido, nadie los lanza. el **for** no devuelve ninguna excepcion¿me entiendes?, y eso lo señalo en la ultima parte de mi respuesta como una nota.

Comment: @eyllanesc agregale un return al final del for para que vea lo que quieres decir

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor por otro lado a mi parecer es mejor evitar try-except ya que tiene varios inconvenientes como por ejemplo hacer un codigo menos legible, consumir más recursos, etc, preferiria un None salvo casos excepcionales como en los sockets, pero en python estan muy difundidos, prefiero verificar.

Comment: ¡Adjudicado! Sólo una pregunta más: ¿Por qué no usas `datetime.stfrtime` en el último bloque?

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor ¿por qué lo usaria?

Comment: Lo necesitas para mostrar `resultado` con el mismo formato que tenía cuando se introdujo; es decir, si `entrada_dia` estaba en formato AAAA/MM/DD, `resultado` tiene que estar en ese formato también, es para eso para lo que quieres almacenarlo

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor ¿No creess que lo mas sencillo seria retornar `entrada_dia` e imprimirlo?, entrada_dia ya tiene el formato :)

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor prueba el último código.

Comment: Pensaba que no se podía por ser una variable local de la función y además estar declarada dentro de un bucle

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor `return` retorna cualquier valor, no interesa si esta en un bucle, si es una variable local, global, etc.